# Contact Form 7 can't send attachment more than 6MB to email

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, contact-form-7

[image]

Attachment is uploaded into server. But, unable to send attachment using contact form to email if file is larger than 6MB. Ajax is loading. 
I encounter the following errors:

```
 EMAIL DELIVERY ERROR: the plugin WP Mail SMTP v1.4.1 logged this error during the last time it tried to send an email:
```

Mailer: Gmail

Request Entity Too Large

Request Entity Too Large
Error 413

Here is my setting:

I have increased the following in php.ini:

```js
      
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size=512M
max_execution_time=600
max_input_time=600
memory_limit=1024M
```

CF7 file limit: 20MB

I still can't send file to email if more than 6MB. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried to see the docs? you should check where is the limitation of the file size.

https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: File is uploaded into folder. But can't send it to mail if more than 5MB.

Comment: Increase the file upload limit.

Comment: @WPLearner I have increased the file upload limit on file.php and mail setting as well. File is uploaded into FTP. But, form can't be sent to mail.

Comment: Then it is a problem with mail configurations. Please visit https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/. Please carefully go through.

Comment: @WPLearner I configure on Contact form mail setting  limit: 20MB. it doen't send and still loading. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By default contact 7 set 1MB max size for each uploaded file

so maybe you can set the limit manually as this -> limit:2mb

```
[file file-709 limit:2mb filetypes:pdf]
```