# Where to Edit Footer Text in Customizr theme on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Please help me where to edit footer to remove the text "Powered by Designed with the Customizr Theme ".

```
<footer id="footer" class="<?php echo czr_fn__f('tc_footer_classes', '') ?>">
         <?php do_action( '__footer' ); // hook of footer widget and colophon?> 
    </footer>
```

I have tried to add following code in additional CSS. it doesn't work.

```
 .czr-credits {
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Dashboard, go to Appearance > Customize > Advanced options > Additional CSS and enter the following code :

```
.czr-credits {
    display: none;
}
```

**Or, Method 2 :**

This involves creating a child customizr theme which basically overrides it's parents style (including footer as well).

1. Create `inc` directory within child theme
2. Copy `czr-front-ccat.php` from `/public/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc` into this child `inc` directory
3. Modify `czr-front-ccat.php`, around line 9456 in the file is the offending function, replace the two sections that insert the wordpress and customizr references with simple calls to the apply_filters function but with sprintf containing no strings.

resources :

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/designed-with-the-customizr-theme/

https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/35-how-to-customize-the-customizr-wordpress-theme

https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/24-why-and-how-to-create-a-child-theme-with-wordpress

Comment: Hi @Maxim , I've updated alternative method if in case it helps.

Comment: I did it. it worked. Many Thanks, Hasta. My child theme preview on WP panel appearance is blank or plain. Does it appear on your admin panel also ?

Comment: That's great! glad I could help. Regarding the child preview I believe it has something to do with the image thumbnail, maybe you could try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94133 ?

Comment: Million Thanks for your kindness, Hasta. I added screenshot.png under child theme. It appears. _/\_

Comment: I have another problem here. If you can help, please help. I am stuck on there too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900130/contact-form-7-cant-send-attachment-more-than-6mb-to-email

Answer (score 1):

try adding parenting to it

```
body .czr-credits {
    display: none;
}
```